# AppEngine Datatransfer

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am trying to transfer data in the form of objects between a gwt client and the app engine server. The objects i transfer need to be persistable (a blog comment for example). as it turns out AppEngine is uncomfortable to include those persistable objects (annotated as @PersistenceCapable) in the gwt module, because the gwt client cant store such date. Also the gwt client cant call a remote procedure with objects which are not concrete. So there is not the option to define interfaces for accessing those classes.

In short:
GWT Client cant work with interfaces, but also not with persistable annotated classes.

My Question is: how can i design an application which transfers stored data between the gwt client and the appengine. This is currently a real problem for me. it seems to me as if the only option is a DataTransferObejct which is just pure sensless code doing the exact thing the data-objects do: storing data.

I used the appengine.datastore Key for the id's of the classes.

Any suggestions ? Or am i getting something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of GWT are you using? I regularly share data between GWT and GAE using serializable POJOs annotated PersistenceCapable. If you are using Key key, use Long id instead to get it working.

Comment: current version. started developing with GAE a few days ago and ended up using gwt too. so you have one class, bot used by server and client, containing a PersistenceCapable annotation ? this leads to an exception in my environment, stating that the used datastore api couldn't be found.

Comment: Yes. How are your DTOs packaged?They should be under shared, implement Serializable and have a default constructor.

Comment: Yes, and i added the "shared" package as a part of the module declaration. Also they implement Serializable. As I said before, compiling and then calling the module via the browser leads to an exception. What structure does your model declaration for the gwt module have ?

Comment: Strange. Most probably you are using some class which is not white listed. Can you post your exception stack trace?

Comment: Hey, i found out that the @Persistent tag is not the problem. its the "@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)" and "private Key key;" annotation for which i need to import the datastore.key. this ends , while loading the module in "[ERROR] [...] LINE The import com.google.appengine.api.datastore cannot be resolved"

Comment: Jepp, figured that out, too. Edit your answer accordingly and i will marke it as right. Thanks for the help.